# How to change WooCommerce loop product title HTML output in single product page and archive page

Tags: plugin-development, functions, woocommerce-offtopic, html, conditional-tags

I'm currently working on designing my custom WooCommerce theme and wondering how I could change the HTML output of loop_product_title in single product page and in archive pages.

I have less knowledge of functions but I made this content but it did not work. I just want the loop product title to have  element and in archives pages to have .

```
if ( is_product() ){
function woocommerce_template_loop_product_title() {
echo '<h2 class="product-title">' . get_the_title() . '</h3>';
}
elseif ( is_shop() ){
function woocommerce_template_loop_product_title() {
echo '<span class="product-title">' . get_the_title() . '</span>';
}
}
}
```

Please someone help me out. I have tried the best of what I could.

Comment: This code has syntax errors, they're hidden because you did not indent your code, but if you do add indenting the error will be super obvious. Otherwise you can't change the start of a function definition using if else statements, `if (...) { function A(){ } else { function A(){ }` is not valid code and does not make sense, you can't "meta-program" like that. Maybe in a compiled language like C++ where you can use macros and a pre-processor, but not PHP. A function has to be defined in full

Comment: Tom, could you please help with it. Like I mentioned, I am bad at php and functions. Is there a way to make the code work?

Comment: Indent the code and the problem becomes really really obvious, like how bullet points get indented, if you're not  sure what I mean by that, see here: https://codehs.gitbooks.io/introcs/content/Programming-with-Karel/how-to-indent-your-code.html, code that isn't indented is very hard for other people to read, and hides trivial mistakes that break your code

Comment: can you please offer a correct code buddy? please!

Comment: edit your question to indent your code, keep in mind any answers you get here will not be copy paste snippets

Comment: Basically I want to have <h2> tags in loop title html when they are being opened in archives like search page or category. But, when I open them in single product page in related posts section, I want it to change into <span> element from <h2>

Comment: I hope you get what I am trying to say

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problems with what you've got are tha

1. your close bracket `}` for the is_product() case is in the wrong place: it should be before the `elseif` not at the bottom of the block. (This is what Tom meant by indenting your code correctly: if you'd indented each {...}, which your IDE will do for you, this would have been obvious.)
2. this code, defining the functions, will run before WordPress has enough state loaded to determine is_product() or is_shop(): at the point the theme is loaded the main query hasn't been initialised yet.

It is OK to wrap function definitions in if-else, e.g. see WordPress's pluggable.php or indeed wc-template-functions which is what you're overriding here, but that's not the correct approach for this. Instead, test is_product and is_shop inside the function:

```php
function woocommerce_template_loop_product_title() {
    if ( is_product() ){
        echo '<h2 class="product-title">' . get_the_title() . '</h2>';
    } elseif ( is_shop() ) {
        echo '<span class="product-title">' . get_the_title() . '</span>';
    }
    // do you need an 'else' case here too?
}
```

because by the point this function is called WordPress will have loaded enough page state for is_product and is_shop.

Comment: Thank you Rup. Like I mentioned, though I have good knowledge of html, css and javascript, I am new to WordPress's dynamic PHP codes.

Comment: Thanks for the answer buddy.